# Sum in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I try this query to get VName sum. in table VName datatype is varchar

```
Select distinct tblRV.ID as ID, 
tblRV.OName,
tblRV.RegNo,
tblvv.VName,
count( tblvv.VName) as total, 
tblRV.MA,
tblRV.MSpeed
from tblRe 
inner join tblRV
On tblReG.RID = tblRV.RID
inner join tblvv 
on tblRV.ID=tblVV.MID 
WHERE 
tblRe.StartDate >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
 tblRe.EndDate <= '2016-07-31  23:59:59.000' and
 tblRe.Region = ‘UK’ and
 VName <> ''
 group by 
tblRV.ID ,
tblRV.OName,
tblRV .RegNo,
tblRV.MA,
tblRV.MSpeed,
tblRV.VName
 order by
 tblRV.OName,
 tblRV.ID
```

WHEN I TRY above query this show result like this

```
ID     OName    RegNo   VName   total   MA  MSpeed
26626   john    BE       MV      3      754 130
26765   john    BE       MV      3      90  140
24569   john    BE       DDSB     6     4   19
27569   john    BE       MV       2     62  129
21231   john    BE       MV       3     66  136
```

now i want to omit VName and want all total of VName AND MAX value of MA and MSpeed

i.e.

```
ID      OName   RegNo       total   MA  MSpeed
26626   john    BE           17    754  136
```

for i try  @The Shooter query  query in this query i only add top(1) so when i add this show total 3 whereas i want total 17

```
    SELECT 
    S.ID
    ,S.OName
    ,S.RegNo
    ,SUM(Total) vNameSum
    ,MAX(S.MA) MaxMA
    ,MAX(S.MSpeed) MaxMSpeed
FROM 
(
    SELECT top (1)
        tblRV.ID as ID, 
        tblRV.OName,
        tblRV.RegNo,
        tblvv.VName,
        COUNT(tblvv.VName) as total, 
        tblRV.MA,
        tblRV.MSpeed
    FROM tblRe 
    INNER JOIN tblRV
    ON tblReG.RID = tblRV.RID
    INNER JOIN tblvv 
    ON tblRV.ID=tblVV.MID 
    WHERE 
        tblRe.StartDate >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00.000'
        AND tblRe.EndDate <= '2016-07-31  23:59:59.000'
        AND tblRe.Region = ‘UK’
        AND VName <> ''
    GROUP BY 
        tblRV.ID
        ,tblRV.OName
        ,tblRV.RegNo
        ,tblRV.MA
        ,tblRV.MSpeed
        ,tblRV.VName
    ORDER BY
        tblRV.OName
        ,tblRV.ID
) S
GROUP BY
S.ID
,S.OName
,S.RegNo
```

so above query show result like this

```
ID     OName    RegNo   VName   total   MA  MSpeed
26626   john    BE       MV      3      754 130
```

wheras i want total 17 not 3

Comment: how can you SUM names? do you mean COUNT?

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: What is the name of the column which values are (3,3,4)?

Comment: VName @Serg 3,3,4 is beacuse i use count thats hwy 3,3,4 is display now i want to use sum so i want to get value 10

Comment: Do you mean VNAME values are really ('3','3','4')?

Comment: no .. there is some text in VName like SA, BA,PA,DSB,BA i just want these all values

Comment: check update @Serg

Comment: check update @Matt

Comment: Then `sum(total) as total` and omiit VNAME from SELECT clause

Comment: total is not column VName is column .. i want to omit VName and get all total of VName against ID i.e. John total of VName is 7 @Serg

Comment: @user6628729 Remove ORDER BY clause from the inner query and id from the group by clause and select list and you should get the result. Also why are you using TOP(1). If you use that clause you will only get one record from the inner query and it will not work so don't use TOP clause. I have modified the query in my answer according to this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I just modified your query):

```
SELECT 
    S.OName
    ,S.RegNo
    ,SUM(Total) vNameSum
    ,MAX(S.MA) MaxMA
    ,MAX(S.MSpeed) MaxMSpeed
FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        tblRV.OName,
        tblRV.RegNo,
        tblvv.VName,
        COUNT(tblvv.VName) as total, 
        tblRV.MA,
        tblRV.MSpeed
    FROM tblRe 
    INNER JOIN tblRV
    ON tblReG.RID = tblRV.RID
    INNER JOIN tblvv 
    ON tblRV.ID=tblVV.MID 
    WHERE 
        tblRe.StartDate >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00.000'
        AND tblRe.EndDate <= '2016-07-31  23:59:59.000'
        AND tblRe.Region = ‘UK’
        AND VName <> ''
    GROUP BY 
        tblRV.OName
        ,tblRV.RegNo
        ,tblRV.MA
        ,tblRV.MSpeed
        ,tblRV.VName
) S
GROUP BY
S.OName
,S.RegNo
ORDER BY
tblRV.OName
```

Comment: this show error..
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.  @The Shooter

Comment: @user6628729 Remove the ORDER BY Clause from Inner query and ID from group by and select list and it should work fine.

Comment: means i put order by at the end ?@The Shooter

Comment: there is one problem i must put ID beacuse the query data is display in table and from that table there is records so according to ID i done some another work .. when i remove id this show error on code.

Comment: Your output says you want to sum up total of vName for john and so on for others. In such case you can't put id in your select list because you are grouping by the name and putting id in group would result in what you have already seen.

Comment: same i  done with tblRV.MA but this show wrong figures.. means i also want to get sum of MA

Comment: @user6628729 Do a count on tblRB.MA in inner query and then sum in outer query as you have done for tblvv.VName.

Answer (score 1):

You probably intend `COUNT()` or `COUNT(DISTINCT)` rather than `SUM()`. You already have `GROUP BY`, so don't use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
Select tblRV.ID, tblRV.oName, tblRV.RegNo,
       count(distinct tblvv.VName) as total, -- number of different names
       max(tblRV.Speed),
-------^ Your comment suggests that this should be `SUM()`
       tblRV.MA
from tblRe inner join
     tblRV
     On tblRe.RID = tblRV.RID inner join
    tblvv 
     on tblRV.ID = tblVV.MID 
where tblRegion_Uni.StartDate >= '2016-07-01' AND 
      tblRegion_Uni.EndDate < '2016-07-29' and
      tblRegion_Uni.Region = 'uk' and
      VName <> ''
group by tblRV.ID, tblRV.OName, tblRV.RegNo, tblRV.MA
order by tblRV.OName, tblRV.ID
```

Comment: no i dont use count .. actually in monthly data VName occur 3 times for 1 user so i want to sum i.e.`1  john 3  1 john 3 1 john 4 so i want 1 john 10`

Comment: I think you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  And sample data should go in the question, not a comment, so you should edit your question.

Comment: i use count thats hwy 3,3,4 is display now i want to use sum so i want to get value 10

Comment: @user6628729 . . . You probably need to remove columns from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.  Without a clearer question (sample data, desired results), it is hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `COUNT` not `SUM`, also don't use `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY`.

Side note: `tblRegion_Uni` isn't in the `FROM` part?
Side note 2: Could `AND tblvv.VName <> ''` be `AND tblvv.VName IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT 
tblRV.ID AS ID, 
tblRV.oName,
tblRV.RegNo,
COUNT(tblvv.VName) AS total,
MAX(tblRV.Speed),
tblRV.MA
FROM tblRe
INNER JOIN tblRV ON tblRe.RID = tblRV.RID
INNER JOIN tblvv ON tblRV.ID = tblVV.MID 
WHERE tblRegion_Uni.StartDate >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00.000'
AND tblRegion_Uni.EndDate <= '2016-07-28  23:59:59.000'
AND tblRegion_Uni.Region = 'uk'
AND tblvv.VName <> ''
GROUP BY tblRV.ID, tblRV.OName, tblRV.RegNo, tblRV.MA
ORDER BY tblRV.OName, tblRV.ID
```

Comment: i dont want to use count

Answer (score 0):

select ID,OName ,RegNo,count(vname) as total,Max(MA) as MA,Max(MSpeed) as Mspeed
from table_name
group by  OName;